# PHP Calendar to show years

Tags: php

I have some code for a calendar. it works and displays as it should. However, I was wondering is there a way to display years? 
At the moment it just shows current year (2018) but i would like for it to have buttons on side to go to next year, 2019 etc..

See code below. Can anyone help?

Comment: It's worth noting that there is a HTML5 date input that could be useful to you. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date

Comment: your end result should be a matrix of days, with blanks for weekdays where it  would belong to an other month ?

Comment: @B3none yeah but i want full calendar view to be displayed on my page.

Comment: @zedling it displays the months jan-dec year(2018) and dates for each month. What i need is yearly view not just one year.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

You will need to pass an additional param to the query, in my example: `y`
With this, you will be able to create links to years like: 
`/page.php?y=1999&m=4`

```
$monthArg = !empty($_GET['m']) ? intval($_GET['m']) : date('m');
$yearArg  = !empty($_GET['y']) ? intval($_GET['y']) : date('Y'); // you will need to add an other query parameter for this

$currYear  = $yearArg;
$startDate = strtotime($currYear . "-" . $monthArg . "-01 00:00:01");
$startDay  = date("N", $startDate);
$monthName = date("M",$startDate );

$daysInMonth = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, date("m", $startDate), date( "Y", $startDate));
$endDate     = strtotime($currYear . "-" . $monthArg . "-" .  $daysInMonth ." 00:00:01");

$endDay = date("N", $endDate);

if ($startDay> 6)
    $startDay = 7 - $startDay;

$currElem        = 0;
$dayCounter      = 0;
$firstDayHasCome = false;
$arrCal          = [];

for($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i ++) {
    for($j= 0; $j <= 6; $j++) {
                // decide what to show in the cell
        if($currElem < $startDay && !$firstDayHasCome)          
            $arrCal[$i][$j] = "";
        else if ($currElem == $startDay && !$firstDayHasCome) {
            $firstDayHasCome= true;
            $arrCal[$i][$j] = ++$dayCounter;
        }
        else if ($firstDayHasCome) {
            if ($dayCounter < $daysInMonth)
                $arrCal[$i][$j] = ++ $dayCounter; 
            else
                $arrCal[$i][$j] = "";   
        }                           

        $currElem ++;               
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is $currMonth?

Comment: it is the same as `$monthArg`